# What is the type of a covariant generic list that contains different types?

Tags: scala, generics, covariance

I have played around with generics in Scala and created the following:

```
package playingaround.playground

object myList extends App {

  abstract class MyList[+T] {
    def head: T
    def tail: MyList[T]
    def isEmpty: Boolean
    def add[C >: T](int: C): MyList[C]
    def printElements: String
  }

  object Empty extends MyList[Nothing] {
    override def head: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException
    override def tail: Nothing = throw new NoSuchElementException
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = true
    override def add[C >: Nothing](int: C): MyList[C] = new Cons(int, Empty)
    override def printElements: String = ""
  }

  class Cons[+T](h: T, t: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T] {
    override def head: T = h
    override def tail: MyList[T] = t
    override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
    override def add[C >: T](int: C): MyList[C] = new Cons(int, this)
    override def printElements: String = if (t.isEmpty) "" + h else h + " " + t.printElements
  }

  // Define lists
  val intList = new Cons(1, new Cons(2, new Cons(3, Empty)))
  val strList = new Cons("a", new Cons("b", new Cons("c", Empty)))
  val mixList = new Cons("a", new Cons(2, new Cons(0.5, Empty)))
  // Print them
  println(mixList.printElements) // a 2 0.5
}
```

What confuses me is how "mixList" works. What type is mixList? And if I were to define it's type explicitly in the val, what would I have to define it as?

Comment: If you were to add the type ascription to the `mixList` declaration it would be type `Cons[Any]`, which is a pretty bad sign. Whenever you see the type `Any` it's a pretty good indication that something has gone off the rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just add that you can always see the type of something in REPL

```
scala> abstract class MyList[+T]
defined class MyList

scala> object Empty extends MyList[Nothing]
defined object Empty

scala> class Cons[+T](h: T, t: MyList[T]) extends MyList[T]
defined class Cons

scala> val mixList = new Cons("a", new Cons(2, new Cons(0.5, Empty)))
mixList: Cons[Any] = Cons@67d32a54
```

Alternatively you can see the type with the following function

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.{TypeTag, Type, typeOf}
def getType[A: TypeTag](a: A): Type = typeOf[A]

println(getType(mixList)) // Cons[Any]
```

By the way, in Dotty (Scala 3) inferred type of `mixList` is also `Cons[Any]` but you can annotate it manually with type `Cons[String | Int | Double]` or `MyList[String | Int | Double]`.

Answer (score 2):

`maxList` is `Cons[Any]`

Covariance basically means that the type matching for `T` also works for `MyList[T]`. In other words, if `T1` is a subtype of `T2`, you can use a `MyList[T1]` where `MyList[T2]` is required.

So when compiling a call to

```
Cons[+T](h: T, t: MyList[T])
```

the compiler will use the same type matching as it would for

```
Cons[+T](h: T, t: T)
```

It will pick a `T` that is compatible with the types of both `h` and `t`. This process is repeated for each call to `Cons` so that the resulting type is one that is compatible with all the types of all the `h` values in all the `Cons` objects.

In this case, the only type that is compatible with `"a"`, `2`, and `0.5` is `Any` because that is the only type compatible with `String`, `Int`, and `Double`.

Comment: Actually inferred type of `maxList` is `Cons[Any]`, not `MyList[Any]`.